# How to split array to many arrays where id same linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have array:

```
OrderProduct[] OrderProductsOrder = new OrderProduct[] { 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 1, ProductID = 2, OrderCustomerID = 1 }, 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 2, ProductID = 1, OrderCustomerID = 1 }, 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 1, ProductID = 3, OrderCustomerID = 1 }, 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 2, ProductID = 1, OrderCustomerID = 2 }, 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 1, ProductID = 2, OrderCustomerID = 3 }, 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 2, ProductID = 1, OrderCustomerID = 3 }};
```

How to split this array to three arrays, order by CustomerID, using linq.
Result should be this three arrays:

```
OrderProduct[] Customer1Order = new OrderProduct[] { 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 1, ProductID = 2, OrderCustomerID = 1 }, 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 2, ProductID = 1, OrderCustomerID = 1 }, 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 1, ProductID = 3, OrderCustomerID = 1 }};

OrderProduct[] Customer2Order = new OrderProduct[] 
{new OrderProduct { OrderID = 2, ProductID = 1, OrderCustomerID = 2 }};

OrderProduct[] Customer3Order = new OrderProduct[] {  
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 1, ProductID = 2, OrderCustomerID = 3 }, 
new OrderProduct { OrderID = 2, ProductID = 1, OrderCustomerID = 3 }};
```

Comment: do you consider using GroupBy(x => x.OrderCustomerID) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**, removed the `GroupBy()` suggestion as it was redundant (courtesy of Innat3)

No reason to use `GroupBy()` at all, just use `Where`.

```
OrderProduct[] Customer1Order = OrderProductsOrder.Where(o => o.OrderCustomerID == 1).ToArray();

OrderProduct[] Customer2Order = OrderProductsOrder.Where(o => o.OrderCustomerID == 2).ToArray();

OrderProduct[] Customer3Order = OrderProductsOrder.Where(o => o.OrderCustomerID == 3).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your code is invalid, there is no need for a GroupBy if you are going to filter them with a .Where condition, use: OrderProduct[] Customer1Order = OrderProductsOrder.Where(o => o.OrderCustomerID == 1).ToArray();

Comment: In my zombie mindset, I completely missed that. You're right.

Comment: Might want to Replace o.Key with o.OrderCustomerID though, to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

Start by grouping the entries by `OrderCustomerID`, and constructing an array from each group. After that, add groups to a dictionary:

```
var byCustId = OrderProductsOrder
    .GroupBy(p => p.OrderCustomerID)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());
```

Now you can grab individual arrays with `TryGetValue` or `operator []`:

```
OrderProduct[] customer2Order;
if (byCustId.TryGetValue(2, out customer2Order) {
    ... // Use customer2Order array
}
```